# How do I concatenate strings in C# embedded in Razor page javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, razor

I have a string I'd like to format in a javascript function on a Razor page.
I am currently doing it by concatenating the sub strings.

```
function Foo(actionName, entityName) {
    var message = "Are you sure you want to ".concat(actionName).concat(" ").concat(entityName);
}
```

I would like to be able to call C# directly to concatenate the substrings more cleanly with **something like this**:

```
@var message = $"Are you sure you want to {actionName} {entityName}";
```

How do I do this with embedded C# in the Razor page javascript?

Answer (score 3):

In JavaScript, it's possible to format strings using template literals.

An example from Mozilla's [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) would be:

```
console.log(`Fifteen is ${a + b} and not ${2 * a + b}.`);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function Foo(actionName, entityName) {
    var message = "Are you sure you want to "+ actionName + " " + entityName;
    console.log(message);
}

//or this
function Foo(actionName, entityName) {
    var message = 'Are you sure you want to '+ actionName + ' ' + entityName;
    console.log(message);
}
//or this
function Foo(actionName, entityName) {
    var message = `Are you sure you want to `+ actionName + ` ` + entityName;
    console.log(message);
}
//or this
function Foo(actionName, entityName) {
    var message = [`Are you sure you want to `,actionName,entityName].join(` `);//feel free to use `` or '' or ""
    console.log(message);
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP had in mind.

Comment: @RobertHarvey you have a point.  Julian Goldsmith has already given the answer I would I have given. I thought I should add this for completeness.  This I think is still cleaner than the one in the question.

Comment: I'm new to Razor and was looking at using the embedded  C# features.

Comment: Specifically, I'd like to user something like to be able to define on a Razor page, a string like this $"{personName} has a {petTypeName}"